# Logging to system streams

Tags: websphere-liberty

I'm using Websphere Liberty 8.5.5 on Linux and I'm trying to redirect its logging into Unix syslog. The logging configuration in the server.xml has an entry for copySystemStreams="true", which 
according to the [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Fae%2Frwlp_logging.html) for the server.xml logging should have the following behaviour: 
"If true, write System.out to the system output stream and System.err to the system error stream. If false, System.out and System.err will write to configured logs like messages.log or trace.log, but not to the system streams. The default value is true."

However, I do not see any Liberty entries in syslog if I set copySystemStreams to true. Am I misunderstanding the documentation or is this a missing piece of functionality?

```
Peter
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this page from the Liberty documentation [Liberty profile: Logging and Trace](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.iseries.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F2-16-0-0&lang=en), it has newer, more accurate description of this field. So it will not log to the `syslog`, no matter what is set in `copySystemStreams`.

> `copySystemStreams`
>
> If true, messages written to the System.out and System.err streams
>   are copied to `console.log.` If false, those messages are written to
>   configured logs such as `messages.log or trace.log`, but they are not
>   copied to `console.log`. The default value is true.